# Does the question reputation increase apply to Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51

Recently, [the reputation for question upvotes to the asker increased from 5 to 10 reputation per question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/).

On Area 51, I still seem to have 5 Internet points per question. Area 51 doesn't have answers. The [Area 51 FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) states that question upvotes gain 5 reputation points.

Is this reputation increase meant to cover Area 51?

Comment: Nobody cares about Area 51 it seems.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - Or those that did care _mysteriously vanished_...

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know the answer to this question is **no**. Area 51 runs under a different software and is not affected by this change.

Comment: Rather, a fork of an earlier version of the Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange software.